# Is “bright example” correct?

Tags: meaning

Can I use "bright example" to mean a good example of something just has been  described. For example:

> Such devices never work more than a year, my mp3 player is bright example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase “bright example” is certainly used rather commonly in English, but the adjective *bright* in this case has some meaning of “intelligent” or “morally right”. Typical examples of its use (found using Google Books):

> - Her mother was a devoted Christian, of deep religious experience and strong faith ; a bright example of perseverance in well-doing
> - The public life of Judge Howell presented a bright example of integrity of purpose, sound judgment[…]
> - Let us not be slow in following such a bright example, lest other nations step in and bear away the honor that now awaits this country if she does her duty.

For an adjective without this connotation, I would recommend using ***an apt example*** (*apt* meaning here “appropriate or suitable in the circumstances”). It is widely used:

> - An apt example […] of a designed, non-social order is a machine, while an example […] of an undesigned, non-social order is a biological organism.
> - Feldman's article provides an apt example of virtually all the habits of mind that mark what one might call the postmodern sensibility, combined with self-righteous moralism